# Do I need to ask users whether or not I can track them with Mixpanel events - iOS

Tags: ios, privacy, policy, mixpanel

I'm developing iOS app, friends of mine suggested me to use some tracking system, to find out how "really" people are using my app, analyze result. And pivot if needed.

I decked  to use Mixpanel system. Do I need to to ask user about permission ? I just wonder that somebody could be offended by tracking. On the other hand data is anonymous.

What Apple says about tracking ?

Can I easily disable Mixpanels's track method ([https://mixpanel.com/site_media/doctyl/uploads/iPhone-spec/Classes/Mixpanel/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/Mixpanel/track:properties](https://mixpanel.com/site_media/doctyl/uploads/iPhone-spec/Classes/Mixpanel/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/Mixpanel/track%3aproperties):) or I need to check some flags myself ?

PS:

I also have some doubts about the fact, that my app don't use network connection at all (besides buying in app purchases). And I wonder that user could be not aware that I track his behaviour and send it to the serwer (using network conneciton)

Answer (score 2):

According to the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html), you may not transmit data about a user without permission:

> 17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to information about how and where the data will be used

There is even a more specific guideline regarding collection information on minors:

> 17.4 Apps that collect, transmit, or have the capability to share personal information (e.g. name, address, email, location, photos, videos, drawings, the ability to chat, other personal data, or persistent identifiers used in combination with any of the above) from a minor must comply with applicable children's privacy statutes, and must include a privacy policy

I suspect this isn't the case here, but if you include location information, you must request permission for that, too:

> 4.1 Apps that do not notify and obtain user consent before collecting, transmitting, or using location data will be rejected

Whether you can collect non-identifying information (e.g. anonymous app usage information), is less clear. If you collect anything, though, your app should disclose its privacy policy regarding both identifying and non-identifying information.

Comment: Well, Mixpanel show some "vague" location data like "Voivodership/Satate", City as well as Country. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/spa/gmrijgfzisraod9/tn_kna8t.png

Comment: @bluesm It probably comes down to how the device is identified. E.g., Apple seems to have cracked down on Mixpanel's use of the IDFA. http://techcrunch.com/2014/02/03/apples-latest-crackdown-apps-pulling-the-advertising-identifier-but-not-showing-ads-are-being-rejected-from-app-store/